# send a url to a desktop application through a chrome extension

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, youtube-dl

I am trying to provide a way to send a url in chrome to a program/application on the user's desktop through a chrome extension. More specifically, I would like to create a chrome application that, when activated, will send the url (most likely from youtube) that the user has open, to a program on the desktop that will rip music from youtube videos. The desktop program is working and is written in python, all I want to be able to do now is click a button  in chrome (chrome extension) and have the url of the website be sent to the desktop application. The only way that I know of that would let me do this is to use NPAPI but it is being phased out.

Comment: Just a heads-up: such an extension would violate Chrome Web Store TOS and be deleted if you were to upload it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) which would require you to setup the desktop application as a native messaging host.

Then you can use the `chrome.runtime` API with commands like `connectNative`, `sendNativeMessage` etc